# Agregar un filtro para salga información individualizado y toda la base

Tags: php, sql

estoy aprendiendo a usar PHP, les comento mi inconveniente, cree una base de datos SQL con datos de paciente (tipo de examen, fecha de examen, medico tratante, etc), todo esto tengo en una tabla designada como "registration". Al crear la página donde se pueda ver los resultados de esos exámenes al medico tratante, esto sale los resultados de todos los pacientes, y solo quiero que salga la información del paciente a través del medico tratante.

Les comparto el código que inserte para que me ayuden a revisar por favor.

```
    <?php   
$aid=$_SESSION['id'];
$aid=$_SESSION['tratanteid'];
$ret="select * from registration ";
$ret="select * from tratanteid ";
$stmt= $mysqli->prepare($ret) ;
//$stmt->bind_param('i',$aid);
$stmt->execute() ;//ok
$res=$stmt->get_result();
$cnt=1;
while($row=$res->fetch_object())
      {
        ?>

<tr><td><?php echo $cnt;;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->firstName;?> <?php echo $row->middleName;?> <?php echo $row->lastName;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->regNoid;?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->fechaimagen;?></td>
<td>

<a href="<?php echo $row->resultado;?>"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    <?php
$cnt=$cnt+1;
                                     } ?>
```

Comment: Hola, Cristian, en este caso, según lo planteas, debes ejecutar una búsqueda anidada en tu consulta SQL para poder obtener la información del paciente a través del médico tratante. Si dejas más información de tus tablas y sus relaciones, creo que podrían ayudarte

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad. Hace falta que agregues el esquema de tus tablas y de ser posible algunos datos de prueba para tratar de reproducir el escenario. Te sugiero hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas cómo funciona la comunidad, ganes medallas y nos ayudes a ayudarte :). También te sugiero investigar un poco sobre la cláusula `INNER JOIN`, creo que puede ayudar en tu situación.